# How to stop SSH filesystem from discarding root permissions after every command?

Tags: bash, ssh, scripts, remote, sshfs

i have a small bash script that mounts my sshfs...

problem is it ask for the server/host password for every mount...

i have four mounts and i have to enter it every time for 4 times and its tiresome, also i want to make it mount at boot/login...

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo fusermount -u /mnt/ctb
sudo fusermount -u /mnt/dtb
sudo fusermount -u /mnt/etb

sudo sshfs -o allow_other 192.168.1.10:/media/ctb /mnt/ctb
sudo sshfs -o allow_other 192.168.1.10:/media/dtb /mnt/dtb
sudo sshfs -o allow_other 192.168.1.10:/media/etb /mnt/etb
```

after every mount comman it ask me for the password of a user on the machine 192.168.1.10...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try generating a ssh key with `ssh-keygen` on your client system, and place the `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` public key in `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the 192.168.1.10 system. 
See [How to harden an SSH server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2271/how-to-harden-an-ssh-server/2279#2279) for more info on this.

Add yourself to the `fuse` user group, if you haven't.   You can use `sshfs user@system` instead of `sudo` there if that is set up correctly.

Also read the [Ubuntu sshfs wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS) if you haven't.

Comment: did that still no luck

Comment: OKay got it...... just went through my brain for an analytic common sense analysis..

realised that i was generating ssh-keygen from my account, 
did it for root user too and bam it works!!!! thanks marking as answered