# Protect SSH server - 3 attempts at one day

Tags: ssh

3 day of action Ubuntu Server 14:)

```
grep sshd.*Did /var/log/auth.log | tail -50

Feb 14 09:41:35 mantykora sshd[3797]: Did not receive identification string from 88.249.106.23
Feb 14 10:17:18 mantykora sshd[4027]: Did not receive identification string from 94.102.48.193
Feb 15 01:41:04 mantykora sshd[17267]: Did not receive identification string from 79.71.81.207
Feb 15 02:31:55 mantykora sshd[17321]: Did not receive identification string from 113.108.21.16
Feb 15 09:07:58 mantykora sshd[19183]: Did not receive identification string from 58.49.91.194
Feb 15 15:54:03 mantykora sshd[3128]: Did not receive identification string from 62.210.24.250
Feb 15 19:12:11 mantykora sshd[3723]: Did not receive identification string from 117.253.221.81
Feb 16 10:08:41 mantykora sshd[4953]: Did not receive identification string from 122.241.63.225
Feb 17 02:01:40 mantykora sshd[5839]: Did not receive identification string from 198.251.79.208
```

I'm trying to protect using sudo `ufw limit OpenSSH` 3 attempts at one day, but I do not know how to do it. How to do it?

Comment: you can allow a single ip. if you're connecting from your office to a server.`/etc/hosts.allow`

Comment: and how to do it with the ufw? `sudo ufw allow from 15.15.15.0/24 to any port 22` this is correct?

Comment: Yeah. That's correct.

Comment: and what wit `ufw limit OpenSSH` ? Can I limit the number of connections ?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish man . if you want to protect your server, first you've to change the ssh port, then deny all the connections except from the ips you believe

Comment: something like Vyatta `rule 12 limit rate 2/second` I do not know if this is possible in ubuntu

Comment: You can use `fail2ban` : see [How to harden an ssh server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2271/how-to-harden-an-ssh-server) . IIRC `maxretry` is set to 3 by default, so you probably don't even need to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the SSH listening port will prevent these robot attacks.

Quick edit: This isn't exactly a long-term fix, but it'll stop those Chinese robots trying simple username & password combinations on most new SSH connections running on port 22.

Comment: I changed - 9603

Comment: This seems like security-by-obscurity at best

Comment: 1. I changed port `9603`
2. `sudo ufw limit 9603`